# mysql return value even if it is null

Tags: mysql

I have a query that returns value if the date range is match. and if it is not match it returns nothing.

```
SELECT start, end
FROM (`taxemployee`) 
LEFT JOIN `project_staff_assignment` ON `project_staff_assignment`.`taxemployee_id` = `taxemployee`.`id` 

 WHERE (start >= '2014-09-01' AND end <= '2014-09-15')
    OR (end >=  '2014-09-15' AND start <= '2014-09-01')

GROUP BY `taxemployee`.`id` 
ORDER BY `assigned_hours`ASC
```

if I put this on WHERE

```
OR coalesce(`start`, `end`) IS NULL
```

it returns null values, but not includes with value

How do I return result even if it is null and with value

here is sqlfiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8bbe4/3

Comment: It's helpful (and good practice) to qualify ALL your columns - in just the same way that you have done with `taxemployee.id`. Failing that, it would be useful to see proper DDLs.

Comment: Please, provide an sqlfiddle with test data

Comment: What does 'not includes with value' mean?

Comment: pls see the sqlfiddle. thanks

Comment: Post it here. Edit it into your question. Questions here should be complete  and self-sufficient. Otherwise they have no permanent value and are liable to deletion.

Comment: The result of the query is correct. It should produce nothing. If you add your `OR COALESCE(...) IS NULL` it should produce multiple `NULL` rows. What is it you want to query?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8bbe4/3

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

Refer fiddle here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2babf/2

I am using case statement to display the date if it falls in the range and am displaying null if not.

```
SELECT `taxemployee`.`id`, Nickname, 
case when project_staff_assignment.startdt >= '2014-09-01' THEN project_staff_assignment.STARTdt ELSE NULL  END AS STARTDATE,
case when project_staff_assignment.ENDdt >= '2014-09-15' THEN project_staff_assignment.ENDdt ELSE NULL END AS ENDDATE
FROM (`taxemployee`) 
LEFT JOIN `project_staff_assignment` ON `project_staff_assignment`.`taxemployee_id` = `taxemployee`.`id` 

GROUP BY `taxemployee`.`id` 
ORDER BY `taxemployee`.`id`  ASC
```

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

Refer Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8bbe4/52

```
SELECT `taxemployee`.`id`, Nickname, start, end
FROM (`taxemployee`) 
LEFT JOIN `project_staff_assignment` ON `project_staff_assignment`.`taxemployee_id` = `taxemployee`.`id` 

 WHERE (start >= '2014-08-01' AND end <= '2014-08-15')
    OR (end >=  '2014-08-15' AND start <= '2014-09-01')
    OR coalesce(`start`, `end`) IS NULL

GROUP BY `taxemployee`.`id` 
ORDER BY `taxemployee`.`id`  ASC;
```

Records were not returned because,
Value was available only for 01.08.2014 whereas, your condition was for 01.09.2014