# MYSQL display Null employees on left join

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having difficulty on how to diplay all null values on this query

Here is my [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8bbe4/13).

```
 SELECT project_staff_assignment.taxemployee_id, taxemployee.nickname
  FROM taxemployee 
  LEFT JOIN project_staff_assignment ON project_staff_assignment.taxemployee_id = taxemployee.id
 WHERE taxemployee.id = 4
```

What I wanted to see is also show other employees with null values

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Show an example of what you'd like to see

Comment: Replace left join with left outer join

Comment: you need only null value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8bbe4/34) is what you need.
remove the where condtion. It will return only 1 record since you are explicitly filtering id = 4

```
 SELECT project_staff_assignment.taxemployee_id, taxemployee.nickname
  FROM taxemployee 
  LEFT JOIN project_staff_assignment ON project_staff_assignment.taxemployee_id = taxemployee.id
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8bbe4/34)**

```
 SELECT 
CASE project_staff_assignment.taxemployee_id WHEN '4' THEN project_staff_assignment.taxemployee_id ELSE NULL END AS REQUIRED_FIELD,
taxemployee.id,`EmployeeNumber`, `Fullname`, `Nickname`,`Position`, `level`
  FROM taxemployee 
  LEFT  JOIN project_staff_assignment  ON project_staff_assignment.taxemployee_id = taxemployee.id
```

What is being done is, all the records are selected, and by using `CASE STATEMENT`, if value = 4, then display as 4 else display as NULL.

Comment: How about showing all records while there is a filter id = 4; and show all other records to null

Comment: @freddy: Refer updated fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8bbe4/47. It is exactly what you want.

Comment: I think this is awesome.. by the way can I filter using start and end column.. instead of employee id, i will use start and end date... example... start >= '2014-08-01'

Comment: @freddy: That is another question, which you need to explain further. I am not able to understand what exactly you need. If this answer helped you, please accept as answer by clicking the grey tick mark next to this answer.

Comment: I think you are refering to this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25136019/mysql-return-value-even-if-it-is-null. Having a look at it now. Meanwhile, please accept this answer.

Comment: take a look at this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8bbe4/61  if I changed the date to 2014-09-01 the user Alvin has gone.. but if I changed it to 2014-08-01 its back.. what I need to do is show also the user whether I changed the date..

Comment: I think im looking for some thing like this query   
 SELECT `Nickname`, `taxemployee_id`, `taxemployee`.`id`, `taxemployee`.`Position`,
start,end
FROM (`taxemployee`) 
LEFT JOIN `project_staff_assignment` ON `project_staff_assignment`.`taxemployee_id` = `taxemployee`.`id`  And start >= '2014-08-01'
And end <= '2014-08-15'
AND (end >=  '2014-08-15' AND start <= '2014-08-01')

GROUP BY `taxemployee`.`id` 
ORDER BY `Nickname` ASC

Answer (score 1):

May be something like this

```
SELECT project_staff_assignment.taxemployee_id, taxemployee.nickname
FROM taxemployee 
LEFT JOIN project_staff_assignment ON project_staff_assignment.taxemployee_id = taxemployee.id
WHERE taxemployee.id = 4 OR project_staff_assignment.taxemployee_id IS NULL
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8bbe4/37)**